# Need To Access an Array of Objects with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

When the user selects a machine, I get the id of the machine. From that id I need to get the make and model of the machine.

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
              <div v-for="dosimeter in dosimeters">
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="optDosimeter" v-model="dosimeter_id" :value="dosimeter.id" v-on:click="dosimeter_select">{{dosimeter.nickname}}
                 </label>
              </div>
           </li>
     </ul>
```

**Vue.js**

```
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
              dosimeters:[],
              dosimeter_id:''
       }
     },
     mounted(){
        axios.get('/dosimeters').then((response) => {
                this.dosimeters=response.data;
            });
     },
     methods: {
         dosimeter_select(){
                not sure what to put here
            }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should do something like :

```
  dosimeter_select(){
          let found= this.dosimeters.find(d=>{
                return d.id==this.dosimeter_id
            });

         console.log(found.make);
         console.log(found.model);
        }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works but it takes two clicks. The first click says 'undefined' and then selecting another radio button I get the make and model as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: try to use `on:input` event instead of click like `<input type="radio" name="optDosimeter" v-model="dosimeter_id" :value="dosimeter.id" v-on:input="dosimeter_select">{{dosimeter.nickname}}`

Comment: That didn't do it. It seems like the method is stopping on return.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dosimeter_select()
{
 let machine =  this.dosimeters.find(dosimeter => dosimeters.id===this.dosimeter_id);
  // now you have the machine object
}
```

Comment: Would this be the proper way to access the object? this.dosimeter_model = machine.model;

Answer (score 0):

it should work:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dosimeters:[
      { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
      { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   dosimeterSelected (selectedDosimeter) {
     console.log(`i doing something with dosimeter.id: ${selectedDosimeter.id}`)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li v-for="dosimeter in dosimeters">
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optDosimeter" :value="dosimeter.name" v-on:click="dosimeterSelected(dosimeter)">{{dosimeter.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes now it works.
I used the suggestion from Boussadjra Brahim:

```
dosimeter_select(){
      let found= this.dosimeters.find(d=>{
            return d.id==this.dosimeter_id
        });

     console.log(found.make);
     console.log(found.model);
    }
```

and rather than using radio buttons I made it a select drop down. Also, rather than triggering the method with @click, I used @change.